# compare two profile types

Tags: views, nodes, users

I have two profile type registrations .I am using  [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module.

1) student profile

2) parent profile

I have created `admission_number` field for the student registration. How can I get student admission number while the parent registration OR How do I display the information about his child when he is logged in?

I tried with [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module, But I couldn't able to do it.

Comment: _What_ did you try with the views_php module?

Comment: I might be doing completely wrong, I just created textfields for both profiles where they can enter the Admission Number with some more additional fields, and  used views to get the values of profile type 'student' (It is displaying all students), but I wanted use the condition(admission Number from the Parent profile) to fetch only one student details. How do I compare these two values ?